# Sum of squared Wigner $3j$ symbols

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory, wigner-eckart

Since Wigner $3j$-symbols for $m_1 = m_2 = m_3= 0 $  have the property
$$
\sum_{l_3 = |l_1 -l_2|}^{l_1 + l_2}(2 l_3 + 1)\begin{pmatrix}
l_1 & l_2 & l_3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}^2 = 1
$$

I am wondering what is the analytical solution for the sum of squared Wigner 3j symbols,

$$
\sum_{l_3 = |l_1 -l_2|}^{l_1 + l_2} \begin{pmatrix}
l_1 & l_2 & l_3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}^2 = ?
$$
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Have you worked out some simple examples? like (l1,l2)= (1,1), (1,2), (2,2) ?

Comment: Please edit your question to show how far you got toward a solution, and then where you found something perplexing.  Better questions are when the asker doesn't delegate 100% of the work to us.